# Linking source files by forward declaring without using headers

Tags: c

Goal is to write a program that consists of two source-files. The first (Main.c) contains the main() function and gives the variable i a value. The second source-file (Print.c) multiplies i by 2 and prints it. Print.c contains the function print() which can be called from main(). The output prints a huge number not even divisible by the assigned integer. How do I fix this?

My main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
void print();

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

My print.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int i)
{
    printf("%d", 2 * i);
}
```

Comment: Try passing `i` from `main` to `print` function.  `print(i)`  Also change prototype of print function to `void print (int i)`

Comment: `void print(int i)` declares a function named `print` which take one single `int` argument. `void print()` declares a function named `print` which takes an indeterminate number of indeterminate arguments.

Comment: The title seem to be completely unrelated. The function declaration does not match the definition. And the call is invalid as it is not passing the expected parameter.

Comment: Thank you, removing the forward declare and adding i to the call fixed it. I'm brand new to C and still figuring out the basics.

Comment: You should *not* remove the declaration. You need to fix it instead to match the definition.

Comment: Oh okay that fully fixed, thank you. I assume it was working because VS assumed it was external and pushed through.